# Query works fine with only one LIKE clause, when I add another my results completely change?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently trying to create a little report on our logging, however it isn't working as I expected it to.

I have created a query which works fine when I only have 1 LIKE clause, however when I add an OR to the query, my results get screwed up. I am not sure as to why this is happening. Am I missing grouping or something?

Here is the query where it works:

```
select
s.SupportCode
, s.DateTaken
, s.TakenBy
, s.AllocatedTo
--, p.IndustrySector
from
Support s
join Project p on p.ProjectCode = s.ProjectCode
where
s.DateTaken >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dateadd(m, -6, current_timestamp)),0)
and s.SupportAction like '%RMC%'
```

Here is the result, which is what I want:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════╦═════╗
║ 00074062 ║ 2017-01-25 00:00:00.000 ║ JCH ║ JCH ║
║ 00073482 ║ 2016-12-14 00:00:00.000 ║ ROA ║ FJ  ║
║ 00072764 ║ 2016-11-10 00:00:00.000 ║ ROA ║ ROA ║
║ 00072660 ║ 2016-11-03 00:00:00.000 ║ FJ  ║ FJ  ║
║ 00073818 ║ 2017-01-11 00:00:00.000 ║ ROA ║ FJ  ║
║ 00070844 ║ 2016-09-14 00:00:00.000 ║ ROA ║ FJ  ║
║ 00070988 ║ 2016-09-22 00:00:00.000 ║ ROA ║ ROA ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════╩═════╝
```

Here is the query when I add the other LIKE clauses:

```
select
s.SupportCode
, s.DateTaken
, s.TakenBy
, s.AllocatedTo
--, p.IndustrySector
from
Support s
join Project p on p.ProjectCode = s.ProjectCode
where
s.DateTaken >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dateadd(m, -6, current_timestamp)),0)
and s.SupportAction like '%RMC%'
 or s.SupportAction like '%FJ%'
 or s.SupportAction like '%DG%'
 or s.SupportAction like '%VIC%';
```

Here are the results:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════╦══════╗
║ 00031254 ║ 1996-11-04 00:00:00.000 ║ KGB ║ KGB  ║
║ 00031279 ║ 1996-11-12 00:00:00.000 ║ TB  ║ TMB  ║
║ 00031296 ║ 1996-11-18 00:00:00.000 ║ SPB ║ BJR  ║
║ 00031402 ║ 1997-01-07 00:00:00.000 ║ AJS ║ AJS  ║
║ 00031474 ║ 1997-02-04 00:00:00.000 ║ BJR ║ NULL ║
║ 00031513 ║ 1997-02-19 00:00:00.000 ║ NS  ║ NULL ║
║ 00031538 ║ 1997-02-25 00:00:00.000 ║ SPB ║ SPB  ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════╩══════╝
```

Why is this happening? I can't think as to why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding brackets ?   Without them Your query is not valid. This one should work:

```
 select
    s.SupportCode
    , s.DateTaken
    , s.TakenBy
    , s.AllocatedTo
    --, p.IndustrySector
    from
    Support s
    join Project p on p.ProjectCode = s.ProjectCode
    where
    s.DateTaken >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dateadd(m, -6, current_timestamp)),0)
    and ( s.SupportAction like '%RMC%'
     or s.SupportAction like '%FJ%'
     or s.SupportAction like '%DG%'
     or s.SupportAction like '%VIC%');
```

Comment: That's perfect! I had no idea I needed the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Put parenthesis around all the or clauses, that is the problem. Like this:

```
and (s.SupportAction like '%RMC%'
 or s.SupportAction like '%FJ%'
 or s.SupportAction like '%DG%'
 or s.SupportAction like '%VIC%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
When use multiple 'OR' condition in Where clause must use open and close brackets like this
where
(s.DateTaken >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dateadd(m, -6, current_timestamp)),0))
and (s.SupportAction like '%RMC%'
or s.SupportAction like '%FJ%'
or s.SupportAction like '%DG%'
or s.SupportAction like '%VIC%')
```